# What Causes a Blank Screen When a Registered User Views a Page?

Tags: wss-3.0, forms-authentication

I have a fairly simple page in WSS3. It's basically a web part page with a custom webpart to display some text and a embedded video from Vimeo, a custom webpart to handle newsletter submissions (a simple form) and a couple of document libraries.

I'm using Forms authentication. My admin user can sign in and browse the rest of the site with no problem, but this one particular page causes the user to be presented with a blank white screen. If I view the source of the page I can see the correct markup and the issue only occurs in IE.

When browsing the site anonymously there is no problem.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: I've managed to narrow this down to document libraries. If I add a document library to the page as a webpart, then I get this error in IE.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like a permissions issue of some sort. The odd part of it is that you say that an anonymous user sees things fine while a logged in user doesn't. I would expect the reverse.

Check every object which is involved in displaying each Web Part (files in the file system, list items, documents, etc.) to see if the permissions are correct.

The best thing to do is strip the page down to as little as possible until it works for a logged in user. Then add components back one by one until it breaks again to identify exactly where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I suspect it's files in a particular document library that may be causing the problems.